# How to format date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format date in JS as below to formating as Y-m-d But I want to get ***ymdms***.

```
datestr = current.toISOString().split('T')[0];
resulting_dates.push(datestr);//dates.push(d.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example you can modify the date to get your preferred format :

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d1rk43bc/)

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"+ (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "+ currentdate.getHours() + ":"  + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = datetime;
}

</script>
```